# How to know when call is made and connected?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

hello im using a broadcast reciever to try to find out when a call is "made" and after the call is "made" also when the made call is "connected" i searched around and came up with this code but this works when recievng a call and making a call, all i really need is when the call is made and connected, any help in guiding me in this is appreciated, thank you for your time

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
               @Override
               public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                  String action = intent.getAction();
                  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                          .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                  if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
                       //action for phone state changed
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver call status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Log.d("reciever","entered keep going");
                      if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
                          Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver call connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver call not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        } 
                  }     
               }
            };
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

            registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) you can find all states of call, just make handle this states, like i did:

```
public class PhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Some Action
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //Some Action
            break;
        //case TelephonyManager.ANOTHER_STATE: ...
    }
    }
}
```